# TypeScript define predefined values for model class

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say i have a User class and i need to instance only predefined 'status'. Is this the best way to do it? Is there any other alternative? What`s the right way to do it? Thanks in advance.

```js
export class User {
    constructor(
        username: string,
        email: string,
        status: AccountStatus
    ){}
}

export enum AcountStatus {
    Active = 'Active',
    Suspended = 'Suspended'
}
```

```js
import { User } from 'app/models/user.model'
import { AccountStatus } from 'app/models/user.model'

private user: User;

this.user = new User('username', 'user@user.cm', AccountStatus.Active)
```

Comment: Your class  doesn't have a constructor. So  I guess it wouldn't work ?

Comment: my question is: this is a good use for enum? should i use a custom Type instead?

Comment: Hmm I don't see issue for the use of enum. For conciseness, you may also replace the enum with a union type `'Active' | 'Suspended'`

Answer (score 1):

If most of the users will have a default `Active` status, then you can give a default value to `status` in the constructor as well:

```
class User {
  constructor(
    public username: string,
    public email: string,
    public status: AccountStatus = AccountStatus.Active
  ){}
}
```

Then when you initialize an Active user, you don't need to explicitly pass in the `Active` status every time:

```
let user: User;

user = new User('username', 'user@user.cm')
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=44&pln=14&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxnA9mEAXAyqghqsBnKAbwFgAoKC2OVASwDdgoBeKAcnlodYBozKp0+AA6gAJsFHM2gvCJDjRrMgF8yZOABsseAgFU8wAE5E+lJCDypDYaokMAKU-yFgARhppwo+IyCwRgAC4oS0MaEABzXnJ+KBd3TyhgCCwaDWDQ8KinSniPL0scfGD4JBQMbFwCFlLkNEwivAA6DnpgHIBKQlVSHrINYFRvA0Ng-SMAbjVSH2MWEGAAdyhxh1ZZvwCeNlmAAVmmuAhWDqhp8zxEAaaNRAj7A43-YG5hoybk1I1Xg8KqjumQA).

---

Another possible improvement is you can replace the `AccountStatus` enum with a union type:

```
class User {
    constructor(
      public username: string,
      public email: string,
      public status: 'Active' | 'Suspended' = 'Active'
    ){}
}

let user = new User('username', 'user@user.cm')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give the consumer of your code more flexibility, you can accept either a union of string literals OR a member from your string enum:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QM4B4AqA+KBeKTAbQGsIQB7AM0IF0BuAWAChRIoBlYAJwEsA7AOYBRfkgC2mCgFV+vCvyxQIAD2AR+AE1RQAShADGFbpvSoeAwQBoo5vkOy4CAAwAkAb3jI0WbAF9nJmYWKiR+A2B5figAN0QUAElULnsRMXEodFEJZTUNbT1DY1M7SxtSh2wAChYoWPiIAC4oMJJ+CgB3fitaqApm7PEe5gBKZrjvKF4dLxQMQdx3Xu4IYCRuaIB5ACMAK0NgADoJuaqKEcOBA2RNNCqT6DgdCsERoL8WELCIqKgn1Ag3GAUCqqjA3GarXaXRs4lQggA-M0XmM-qgAUCdGDuFAlsw6rwaFUAITYkZQYAAC24nSg-AgHSgwm4NO4VThr3en2YYOMwI0OQAggYjGFgFw4GsdHi6sLIjFoAQAORy3gKpXDOocJCoSBaCCafBQJXa3X5A0algfYI8lRgPlQa7-KDSDG43pGfh2JARYwg3p1HWA-hwcRNWwWISaurKcRwXgIZGR6wBiOSnXNFKWQZSWRRdBsCDUKDC0X8cXAdOobDR8kymMIVZ-AzNUsUMUSqVBVNwAxG8xV+hQAD0ACpUwA-CepzDgaBKgBEqoVC6gAB8oAvTXrbpoF0qpjp2sD-rxBCHto2KRQKXPjW2O5WpUrDqm6rP2IvlxB94e6RQT3RM8LyvYAb0Le8RXbctOx1F8qgAJgAZgQhDyVHYduRjEdhxLdFAWBXhgW2XsSGvEsoMfKsoCoP1KHWPouhaVA4EEaBCSgeioA6OBy0aHt8KBe4GiSLMhEGKoBylGwHxgp8dRGN4ez7AgpJ1Idh1wigSF6a1rW5TSmRUUMwCvHVWKabl6UZV1ASqJUg24DVjUcgABEMw0OYAEE0ZyVQAYUwaQYGEJU3hHcd8Ww6KYtiuKYynRLEpYQVuEECQNGBYsIK-QLguEX9pn-QDUGAuBL2gMCoDAOBuFDVZAT6GgcqXH4V3XTdt3NPd4OQgAWABWdDMJtayXQxezHL8tyPIgLyfL878wo0rSdOYMbbLZByMWmjF3Pq+bfJkyi5KrQ5v3CwztJYIA)

```ts
type Values<T> = T[keyof T];
type StringEnumToUnion<T extends Record<string, string>> = `${Values<T>}`;

function valueIsStringEnum <Enum extends Record<string, string>>(
  value: unknown,
  o: Enum,
): value is Values<Enum> {
  return Object.values(o).includes(value as string);
}

function assert (expr: unknown, msg?: string): asserts expr {
  if (!expr) throw new Error(msg);
}

export enum AccountStatus {
  Active = 'Active',
  Suspended = 'Suspended',
}

export class User {
  constructor (
    username: string,
    email: string,
    status: StringEnumToUnion<typeof AccountStatus>,
  ) {
    let ac: AccountStatus;

    ac = status; /*
    ~~
    Type '"Active" | "Suspended"' is not assignable to type 'AccountStatus'.
      Type '"Active"' is not assignable to type 'AccountStatus'.(2322) */

    // Assert it back to AccountStatus for your own usage if you want:
    assert(valueIsStringEnum(status, AccountStatus));
    ac = status; // ok
  }
}


// Example usage:

new User('user', 'user@name.tld', 'ACTUVE'); /*
                                  ~~~~~~~~
Argument of type '"ACTUVE"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Active" | "Suspended"'.(2345) */

new User('user', 'user@name.tld', 'Active'); // ok
new User('user', 'user@name.tld', AccountStatus.Active); // ok
```